# Javascript callback to VB.net code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, callback

Previously, I asked a question that had a setup that looked like this:

```
function checkValidate_onBlur(me) {
        var args = me.value;
        performCallback(args, "");
        return false;
    }
    function callbackComplete(result) {
        document.getElementById('<% =txtMyTextBox.ClientId %>').value = result; 
    }

   <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox" runat="server" onblur="checkValidate_onBlur(this)"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

callbackComplete should take a control to, effectively being callbackComplete(result, control)

With ICallbackEventHandler in the code-behind to handle the callbacks.

```
 Public Function GetCallbackResult() As String Implements System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.GetCallbackResult
            Return result
        End Function

        Public Sub RaiseCallbackEvent(ByVal eventArgument As String) Implements System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.RaiseCallbackEvent
            txtMyTextBox_onCallback(eventArgument)
        End Sub
```

The problem is that I want to set up multiple fields that each have their own function associated with them when they fire the callback. There is a C# example on CodeProject that handles this, but A) It's C# which I don't believe converts cleanly to VB due to their Raise event and B) It's spread across multiple files. I'm looking for a simple way to associate the call back with a control, so that each control has its own logic it can perform.

I'd like to do it like the version found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32312/Handle-multiple-client-callbacks-in-ASP-NET

Any advice on where to start? I'm also new to VB.net and JavaScript, so keep that in mind.